# how to get an id from map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react"; 

class MyPics extends Component {
    state = {
        Show: false
    }; 
    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState ({ Show: !this.state.Show });
    }; 
    render() {
        const IMGS1 = [
            {_id: 0, src: "../../../IMG/1.jpg", alt: "IMG0"}, 
            {_id: 1, src: "../../../IMG/2.jpg", alt: "IMG1"}, 
            {_id: 2, src: "../../../IMG/3.jpg", alt: "IMG2"}
        ]; 
        return (
          {
            IMGS1.map(({ _id, src, alt }) => (
                <img key={_id} src={src} alt={alt} style={IMGStyle} onClick={(this.handleClick = _id => console.log(_id))} /> 
            ))
          } 
        );
    }
} 
export default MyPics;
```

Comment: Please post formatted code. Use the formatting tools in the question editor if needed

Comment: i don't know how to formated sorry, they did not allow me to put spaces

Comment: Click on `<>` and use the formatter there if you need to. Also not hard to use an ide to do formatting

Comment: i tryed but they did not allow me, can you edit my code?

Comment: @IMdB209848OfficialTrailer formatted it for you. Let me know if something is missing

Comment: a lot is missing man in the Return @Max Baldwin

Comment: @IMdB209848OfficialTrailer, that is what you had. I formatted from what was available

Comment: @Max Baldwin you missed this in the return:
{IMGS1.map(({ _id, src, alt }) => (
            <img
              key={_id}
              src={src}
              alt={alt}
              onClick={this.handleClick(_id)}
            />
          ))}

Comment: @IMdB209848OfficialTrailer, fixed

Comment: can you do it like this 
{IMGS1.map(({ _id, src, alt }) => ( <img key={_id} src={src} alt={alt} onClick={this.handleClick(_id)} /> ))}
because i need some one to show me how i can get the id

Comment: @IMdB209848OfficialTrailer, you can edit it. Just don't remove the formatting.

Comment: @Max Baldwin i couldn't edit this, but thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modify your class method `handleClick` into a currying function, to avoid calling the function immediately in JSX and crashing the app:

```
handleClick = () => (id) => {
   // id is accesible
};

onClick={this.handleClick(_id)}
```

Comment: did not get your point, can you make yourself more clear please @kind user

Comment: @IMdB209848OfficialTrailer Just copy&paste my answer

Comment: i will try, and i will tell you

Comment: i did this but i couldn't see my _id in state


`handleClick = () => id => {
    this.setState({
      myId: id
    });
    console.log(this.state.myId);
  };
onClick={this.handleClick(_id)`

Comment: @IMdB209848OfficialTrailer It looks fine. Use `console.log(this.state)` inside `render()`

Comment: i get an empty state, i couldn't  get my id number i try every way but still nothing happend, did you try it because i couldn't never see my id get showing

Comment: i get the answer thank you so much for wasting your valuable time with me here's the trick                                                                                               

`handleClick = id => {
    // id is accesible
    this.setState({
      myId: id
    });
  };

onClick={() => this.handleClick(_id)}`

thank i will use your answer as solution because your answer helped me to get this result, thanks again

Comment: The currying function would help there, you don't have to use arrow function in JSX. However no problemo:)